# Debian - "command" command not found

Tags: debian

My shell bash gives me a `bash : ... : command not found` error and I don't know how to start to solve it. Also I had no idea witch tags should be selected except "bash" "Debian".

I'm root, also those two programs are already installed. The OS is Debian Buster and freshly installed. During the process of installation I unticked all the option in Tasksel configuration step. I think is more linked to my Shell.Later, I use to install Awesome tiling windows.

Here the ouput for my path:
`root@machine:~# echo $PATH`
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Here two examples: First I tried to run the program. Second, I check if the program is installed.

```
root@machine:~# modprobe --verbose
bash: modprobe: command not found

root@adrien:~# apt-get install kmod 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done kmod is already the newest version (26-1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@machine:~# openvpn 
bash: openvpn: command not found

root@adrien:~# apt-get install openvpn 
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done openvpn is already the newest version (2.4.7-1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It's probably your PATH, try `PATH=$PATH:/sbin`

Comment: Please include the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: Just try upgrade your system everything.

Comment: How did you switch to root?

Comment: root`@machine` vs root`@adrien` good attempt to hide your hostname, but you need to cover all instances :) or it happened on its own?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak yes:) Both, attempt to hide my hostname and made the prompt clean. And I forgot to check the others instances:)
@annahri I switched using `user@machine:~/$ su`.

Answer (score 5):

Check your `$PATH` and see whether these programs are in it.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

should show what is your system search path.
Compare it with what

```
$ dpkg-query -L <package_name>
```

will show you.

```
$ command -v program
```

will tell you full/absolute path to the program.

If you can't find it this way try:

```
find /sbin modprobe
find /usr/sbin modprobe
```

Modprobe resides in `/sbin` (or it might be in `/usr/sbin`) and is symbolic link to `/bin/kmod`. If you don't have path to directory where modprobe is you won't be able to use it unless you provide full path like `$ /sbin/modprobe`.

You can send result of `$ set | grep PATH` and we may see what's wrong with it.

As your output `PATH` indicates you don't have `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in it, you have to add it in your `$HOME/.bashrc`. To test it first use:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

and check whether it works. If so then add it to `$HOME/.bashrc` and if you want it to be available for every user add it to `/etc/profile` as @GAD3R suggested.

PS. `$` is command prompt, you don't put it in the console, it shows that command is used in shell. In general, for regular user `$` is used as shell prompt indicator and `#` for `root`. Because it can be general problem, not only root, I used `$`. Bear in mind that in your case when you're `root` $ "becomes" # but as you're already logged in as root it won't change anything.

Comment: Here is the output: `root@adrien:/# echo $PATH 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`. There tow missing: `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`.

Comment: Here is the output of `root@machine:~# set | grep PATH`
`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`
`TERMINATOR_DBUS_PATH=/net/tenshu/Terminator2`
`XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0`
`XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0`

If I remember well: # is for administrator and $ for user.

Comment: You have to add `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` to your path, first try this:
`# export PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH`. If it works add these paths to your PATH in `/root/.bashrc`  (PS. Yes, `$` is for regular user, `#` for root., also `$ sudo command` would be equivalent to `# command` )

Answer (score 4):

Note that Debian switched to another branch of the `su` command in Debian 10 ("Buster"). Unlike in previous versions of Debian, it no longer automatically adds `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/local/sbin` to your `$PATH` automatically when you use plain `su` to become root.

This has surprised quite a few people.

You can use `su -` instead to explicitly fully re-initialize the environment when switching to the root user: this will cause the `.../sbin` directories to be included in `$PATH`.

Alternatively, you can automate the addition of the directories to `$PATH` whenever you become root, [as suggested in GAD3R's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572614/258991).

---

> Also I noticed the fact that I can reboot my computer with:
>
> root@machine:~# reboot
>
> instead of.
>
> root@machine:~# systemctl reboot

(Note: the convention on Stack Exchange is to ask just one question on each question post. Multi-questions like this will make it harder for other people with the same problem to find applicable answers.)

This is a compatibility wrapper that allows you to still use the classic SysV style shutdown/reboot commands, which may be deeply embedded in the muscle memory of many long-term Linux/Unix administrators.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Il will erase it from my post. What is your advise because I think this is a symptom.

Comment: In Debian Buster, that is *normal* if you have the `systemd-sysv`package installed. There is a symbolic link `/sbin/reboot -> /bin/systemctl`, so if you used `su -` or `sudo -i` to become root or added `/sbin` to your `$PATH` any other way, you can just run `reboot`. The `systemctl` command will check its `$0` and see it's being called as the "reboot", and will do just that, to maintain compatibility with the old SysV-style `reboot` command. The commands `halt`, `shutdown` and `poweroff` will work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the location of the executable : `$ which modprobe` and `$ which openvpn`

With `su` the commands are

```
# /usr/sbin/modprobe
# /sbin/openvpn
```

With `su -` it becomes

```
# modprobe
# openvpn
```

I.e. only `su -` will provide full root privileges / root's PATH. Which is required for some `/sbin/` and `/usr/sbin/` commands: Debian 10.

Comment: The last version of Debian Administrator's Handbook is from 2015, I will read the last one because I'm not up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/profile` as follows (the first 6 lines):

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

Then reboot your system.

Comment: It was already wrote it.

Comment: @ladentbleu from the output of `echo $PATH`, `/usr/sbin` isn't in your root PATH.

Comment: What is the process that generate the past when the machine is starting ?